range has lost one leg of 220
I have traced/checked the range outlet (an outlet with three taps), black shows 110 but red shows 8. We have two paired 50 amp breaker sets (each set totals 100 amps). There are no other 50 amp breakers. There are two 30 amp. breakers --dryer? and ?? --no labels. To work on the range I shut off one of the two sets of paired 50 amp breakers --nothing else in the house goes off --so I assume that the two 50 amp. breakers are powering the range. Am I correct to assume that one of those two breakers is bad? Do I need to replace both --on Amazon I see them offered in pairs.
Update. From reading the comments and more research online. I now understand that the two breakers tied together are actually one 50 amp. breaker. Answers to some questions: The cover of the breaker box is stamped General Electric. I measured the voltage using a DIgital Multimeter (pictured) --black lead from COM and red lead from the other port, meter set to 600 volts --then black to the post on the back of the outlet with the white wire; red to post with black lead (110 volts); red to post with red wire (8 volts --it actually varies from 4 to 8); black (com) to black wire post and red to red wire post (110 volts).
I removed the breaker panel. The red and black wires attached to the breaker visually match the ones attached to the back of the outlet --there are no other similar wires anywhere in the panel. I checked the voltage across the two breaker post (110) volts.

What does the other 50A breaker shut off?  Does the dryer still heat up normally?

When I turn off the pair (they have a bar holding them together so that they operate as one breaker), I am aware of only the range going off. None of the burners operate. I have not checked the oven.  It would be really strange for there to be 100 amps. for a range.

Usually you want a single breaker with two poles, instead of two singles with a handle tie. Breakers going bad is on the rare side, so test what volts you get at the breaker. Better chance you have a loose/bad connection than a bad breaker.

Have you lost one entire 120 V leg? If the front of the panel is off, you can check where the power comes into the panel. But working with the front off is dangerous. If you are missing one leg about half of the 120 V circuits in the house would be unpowered. Often  a missing leg is a disconnection outside your house. Call the power company and report .

Your range uses 240 Volts at 50 Amps. (BTW you would not add the amps, you'd add the volts, so it's 240V at 50A, not 120V at 100A.) The 240V comes on two legs of 120V (called "split phase"). A 240V breaker in the split-phase electrical setup should always come as a permanently-paired double breaker.
To test the missing leg problem, you'd have to open the circuit breaker panel. Be careful in there: there are things in there that will give you a wild ride for a second, then kill you. So don't indiscriminately touch anything metal in there with bare hands or tools. You can troubleshoot this, but you have to be careful. If you don't feel comfortable with these concerns, or you live in a rental property with a landlord, an electrician should troubleshoot.
Once the circuit breaker panel cover is removed, find the breaker that feeds the range. There will be two screws clamping down the wires going to the range. Set your voltmeter on the setting that will cover 240 volts, then touch the probes to the two circuit breaker wire clamp screws. If there is a full 240 volts between the breaker's wire clamp screws, but only 120V on one side and very little on the other side up at the range outlet, then the breaker is fine, and there is a problem either in the wires between the breaker and range outlet, or in the outlet itself. If you find the same or similar limited voltages at the breaker as at the outlet, then the breaker is bad.
If the breaker's clamp screws showed 240, but the outlet still shows 120/8, we'd next check tightness of the breaker clamp screws. Turn off the breaker, confirm that the 240 is off, then check tightness of the wires clamping into the outlet's screws. (You ought to have a torque screwdriver to do this: proper torque has been shown essential in electrical wiring, even with copper wires.) Look at the range wires' insulation: is it still factory-smooth, or does it look burned and melted? If burned and melted, the breaker's clamp screws haven't been tight enough and most of the missing 120 on the "8" leg has been dissipating as heat. The breaker should be replaced, since this heat could have damaged it, and the wires need to be trimmed and re-stripped for the new breaker.
If the breaker is fine and the clamp screws were tight, with factory-fresh insulation on the wires, then we move testing to the outlet. Turn off the breaker and confirm at the breaker wire clamp screws that the 240V is off. Also test the outlet to confirm the 120 & 8-ish are off. Then remove the outlet from the box. Test the outlet's wire clamp screws to confirm the 120 & 8 volts are gone. Torque-check tightness of the outlet's wire clamp screws, and look at the wires' insulation for factory freshness. Check for places in the wires that seem way too flexible, meaning a broken wire under the insulation, and repair if found. If everything is tight, the insulation is good, and the wires are firm, turn the breaker back on again and test voltage at the outlet clamp screws and outlet holes. If 240 is back, then there was an intermittent connection either in the wires inside the box, a loose connection, or there was a problem inside the outlet. Replacing the outlet might be a good idea, as intermittent connections can dissipate lots of heat and damage.
If after all this the 120/8 or similar is still present at the range outlet but full 240 at the breaker, then there is a problem with the range wires inside the wall between the breaker and the outlet. If there is a junction box along the way where the range wires go in, there could be joins inside the junction box: With power off, open the box and check tightness on the joins. Someone could have driven a wall nail or screw through the range wires, or a rodent got to chewing, etc. If the wires are in conduit, they can be pulled out and inspected (with the power off) and replaced. If they are all together in a sheathed cable, you may need to put in a whole new cable.

A 240V breaker in the split-phase electrical setup should always come as a permanently-paired double breaker. Might be a better statement here. Handle-tied individual breakers have been seen in the wild doing a job that should be done by an actual two-pole breaker. But a 50A single pole is something of a unicorn, as there's no real application for it, unlike a 30A.

Good info & edited in. Thanks, Ecnerwal!

Checked with a multimeter. Across the two screws measured 110 volts (one with a red wire attached and one with a black wire attached --which match the red and black wires attached to the back of the outlet --there are no other similar wires in the breaker box).

@Eddy OK, test across the two 30 amp breakers, too. Are they also 110? If so, your whole house has a problem. If the 30's read full 240, then yo my have a bad 50 amp range breaker.

Problem solved. It was a faulty breaker.  Thank all of you for your help.  I learned a bunch from all of you.
